# What's the easiest way to setup a personal .NET web development environment?

Tags: .net, installation, environment

So I work in .NET Development but wanted to do some of my own, personal development at home. 
I understand the need for source control and multiple development environments. Because I want to start developing right away without the headache of setting up a local, development, and production environment, is there an easy way, solution, or tutorial for setting up a barebones development workflow at home?

**Note: I just finished purchasing Visual Studio 2010 Professional and SQL Server 2008 R2**
Apologies for not letting everyone know that!

Comment: You can install everything (except source control) in one step with Web Platform Installer. http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: @jrummell, why didn't you answer with that instead of commenting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend installing the development tools you need with the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). It has express versions of Visual Studio, SQL Server and many other tools.

For source control hosting, I like [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) since it offers free, private mercurial repositories and wiki and issue tracking.

You could also easily setup a local SVN repository with [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/).

If you're looking for open source project hosting, there [are](https://github.com/) [many](http://code.google.com/hosting/) [options](https://www.codeplex.com/) [available](http://sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Web Platform Installer is great, and exactly what you are looking for to get all of the free tools

Comment: @MaxAlexander I use the [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) mercurial client for BitBucket. There's also a VS Extension called [VisualHg](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @GuyStarbuck these are simply the tools that I've tried and used over the last few years for various personal and open source projects. If there was a comprehensive list, I'd like to know about it.

Comment: @jrummell Thanks a lot this is great! Bitbucket and VisualHg are/were exactly what I was looking for. The jenkins integration is pretty sweet as well! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Download the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) from Microsoft. You can then install Visual Studio Express, MVC3, IIS Express and others from it and should be good to go "quickly" (after hours of installs / reboots)